# RTSP streaming in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, media-player, rtsp

I am shocking there is no any anyone to tell how to run `RTSP` in iPhone I want source code running.

It means there is no anyone who knows `RTSP` play in iPhone. In the other hand there are various apps available in iTunes store like `http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/oplayer-lite-best-free-video/id385907472?mt=8`

If there is any smart guy in the world so pls let me know.

I appreciate it.:)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what kind of question is that??

There are a few open source libraries for rtsp.

The iPhone isn't designed for rtsp and Apple would rather you use http streaming format, so to make it work takes some research and hard work.

https://github.com/mooncatventures-group

Comment: Hi Michelle, I have already hard work on this topic but i didn't fine anything. I have some code which play rtsp but not implemented in Custom Media player. :(